# Function template specialization for both view and strided view and const nightmare

Tags: c++, templates, constants, c++17, array-view

I define a class array_view and a class strided_view (think about array_view and strided_array_view http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0122r0.pdf) and i would like to specialize the way i could iterate on it for efficiency
Let's say I have a function dispatcher which try to specialize different case.

Lets start with some simple code

```
template <class T>
    class view
    {};
template <class T>
    class sview
    {};
template<typename T1, typename T2, template <typename> class View1,   template <typename> class View2>
void PixelWiseUnary(const View1<T1>& i_vin, View2<T2>& o_vout)
{       
    PixelWiseUnaryDispatch<T1, T2, View1, View2> dispatcher;
    dispatcher(i_vin, o_vout);
}
```

Then i define different specialization

```
// primary use strided view 
template<typename T1, typename T2, template <typename> class View1, template <typename> class View2, typename = void>
struct PixelWiseUnaryDispatch
{
    void operator()(const View1<T1>& i_vin, View2<T2>& o_vout) const
    {
        std::cout << "***************" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "primary template" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "***************" << std::endl;

    }
};

template<typename T1, typename T2, template <typename> class View1, template <typename> class View2>
struct PixelWiseUnaryDispatch<T1,T2, View1, View2,
    std::enable_if_t<(!std::is_same_v<T1,T2> && std::is_same_v<View1<T1>,view<T1>> )&& std::is_same_v<View2<T2>, view<T2>>>
>
{
    void operator()(const View1<T1>& i_vin, View2<T2>& o_vout) const
    {
        std::cout << "***************" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "both view != type" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "***************" << std::endl;

    }
};

template<typename T,template <typename> class View1, template <typename> class View2>
struct PixelWiseUnaryDispatch<T,T, View1, View2,
    std::enable_if_t<(std::is_arithmetic_v<T> && std::is_same_v<View1<T>, view<T>>) && std::is_same_v<View2<T>, view<T>>>
>
{
    void operator()(const View1<T>& i_vin, View2<T>& o_vout) const
    {
        std::cout << "***************" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "both view same type" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "***************" << std::endl;

    }
};
```

Then define a simple main

```
void main(void)
{
view<int> vin;
view<float> vinf;
view<int> vout;
sview<int> vsout;
PixelWiseUnary(vin, vsout); //primary template
PixelWiseUnary(vinf, vout); //both view != type
PixelWiseUnary(vin, vout);  //both view same type 
}
```

All is fine and switch properly

But things goes weird when i try to use const
Eg

```
void main(void)
{
view<const int> vin;
view<const float> vinf;
view<int> vout;
sview<int> vsout;
PixelWiseUnary(vin, vsout); //primary template as expected
PixelWiseUnary(vinf, vout); //both view != type WTF i don't provide specialisation for const (cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926482/const-and-non-const-template-specialization) so i expected primary template
PixelWiseUnary(vin, vout); //both view != type WTF i don't provide specialisation for const and i loose the same type specialization
}
}
```

I try to add advice from [Const and non const template specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926482/const-and-non-const-template-specialization) but its change nothing in my case.

What i have missing?
Regards

Note : i work with the lastest Visual2017 community edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can solve the problem 
(1) testing that `!std::is_same_v<T1 const, T2 const>` (instead of testing that `T1` and `T2` arn't the same type) for the `"both view != type"` case
(2) use `T1` and `T2` (instead of `T`) in the `"both view same type"` and adding the test `std::is_same_v<T1 const, T2 const>`

I mean (I have only a C++14 compiler, so I've used `std::is_same<>::value` instead of `std::is_same_v<>`)

```
template <typename T1, typename T2,
          template <typename> class View1,
          template <typename> class View2>
struct PixelWiseUnaryDispatch <T1, T2, View1, View2,
   std::enable_if_t<
         !std::is_same<T1 const, T2 const>::value
      && std::is_same<View1<T1>, view<T1>>::value
      && std::is_same<View2<T2>, view<T2>>::value>
>
 {
   void operator()(View1<T1> const & i_vin, View2<T2> & o_vout) const
    {
      std::cout << "***************" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "both view != type" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "***************" << std::endl;
    }
 };

template <typename T1, typename T2, template <typename> class View1,
          template <typename> class View2>
struct PixelWiseUnaryDispatch<T1, T2, View1, View2,
   std::enable_if_t<
         std::is_same<T1 const, T2 const>::value
      && std::is_arithmetic<T1>::value
      && std::is_same<View1<T1>, view<T1>>::value
      && std::is_same<View2<T2>, view<T2>>::value>
>
 {
   void operator()(View1<T1> const & i_vin, View2<T2> & o_vout) const
    {
      std::cout << "***************" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "both view same type" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "***************" << std::endl;

    }
 };
```

En passant: instead of impose that `View1<T1>` and `View2<T2>` are the same type as `view<T1>` and `view<T2>`, you can (in your specializations) avoid the use of `View1` and `View2` and use `view` directly.

You can semplify your specializations as follows

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct PixelWiseUnaryDispatch <T1, T2, view, view,
   std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<T1 const, T2 const>::value>>
 {
   void operator()(view<T1> const & i_vin, view<T2> & o_vout) const
    {
      std::cout << "***************" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "both view != type" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "***************" << std::endl;
    }
 };
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct PixelWiseUnaryDispatch<T1, T2, view, view,
   std::enable_if_t<
         std::is_same<T1 const, T2 const>::value
      && std::is_arithmetic<T1>::value>>
 {
   void operator()(view<T1> const & i_vin, view<T2> & o_vout) const
    {
      std::cout << "***************" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "both view same type" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "***************" << std::endl;

    }
 };
```

Comment: I completely misunderstood where to put check on constness.... I will try your working solution on my more complicated code :)