# General function for types and const types without overloading

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, template-specialization, generic-programming

I know it's generally a bad idea to rely on SFINAE unless absolutely necessary, but I'm curious about how to do the following anyway.

So let's say I have a function that prints a type to the console (class used for partial specialization since it more closely matches my situation):

```cpp
template <class Ty>
class print
{
public:
    print(Ty line)
    {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Since this is scaled down code, I'm not sure if it would also work with `const` types, but (because does not in my specific case) let's say the above function does *not* work with `const` types. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe this would be how you'd accomplish this with partial template specialization?

```cpp
template <class Ty>
class print <const Ty>
{
public:
    print(const Ty line)
    {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
};
```

However, is there a way to use the `<type_traits>` header to do this? I've come across [a question that was specific to `char*` and `const char*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926482/const-and-non-const-template-specialization), but it seems to be different when generalized. Additionally, that question (and answer) is nearly 7 years old.

I've tried the following code (untested) when trying to adapt the answer from the above question to my own situation, but it seems like there should simply be a better way to accomplish this task. In fact, I'm pretty sure my code won't compile (specifically if `Ty` is already `const`)

```cpp
template <class Ty>
struct print_accept_const :
    std::enable_if<std::is_same<Ty, Ty>::value || std::is_same<Ty, const Ty>>
{};

template <class Ty, class = print_accept_const<Ty>>
class print
{
    print(Ty line)
    {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Just for reference, I'm using partial template specialization because I'm specializing this `print` class for `std::vector` objects, `std::set` objects, `std::unordered_set` objects, etc. If there is a way to do this without SFINAE, then I'd be totally open to that.

**Edit 1**
As asked in a comment, my exact error happens when I try to specialize for `std::unordered_set` objects.

```cpp
template <class ValTy>
class print <std::unordered_set<ValTy>>
{
public:
    print(std::unordered_set<int> lines)  // 'int' instead of 'ValTy' to activate IntelliSense for errors
    {
        const auto last = --lines.end();

        for (auto& line : lines)
        {
            // IntelliSense, for the line below when 'ValTy' is
            // replaced with 'int', says:
            //
            // no instance of constructor "print<std::unordered_set<ValTy, 
            // std::hash<ValTy>, std::equal_to<ValTy>, std::allocator<ValTy>>>
            // ::print(std::unordered_set<int, std::hash<int>, ...>)" matches
            // the argument list. Argument types are (int).
            //
            print<ValTy> p(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Frank Could you explain what you mean a bit more?

Comment: why does it not work with const? Why is using SFINAE a bad idea?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 A lot of companies don't like templates in general because it can be difficult to maintain. For example, [Google says not to use SFINAE in their style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Template_metaprogramming)

Comment: hm ok, get it. Your real example needs to distinguish between `const` and non-const,the example here is fine with both

Comment: google guidelines is full of example of overly protective and conservative guidelines. Consider that those guidelines target a million lines code base with lots of legacy code. Luckily they always give the rationale and you can make your own decision

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I'll add this to the question, but it's because, when trying to do a range-based loop on an `std::unordered_set` to send every element through to the `print` function, I get IntelliSense telling me I can't convert from an `int` (which is what I was using as an example type) to a `const int`. I have a feeling it has something to do with `unordered_set` objects making their keys `const` or something

Comment: not being able to convert an `int` to a `const int` sounds a bit fishy, perhaps it would be better if you show that broken code and ask a question about that (though that would be a different question)

Comment: Btw, yes keys are `const` in `unordered_set`

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I added what I was specifically having problems with to the question. I don't think it's too off-topic here

Comment: I don't see a problem here, except with the invalid line `const auto last = --lines.end();`: https://godbolt.org/z/4JK_kQ Can you provide a [mre] that produces the error you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't clear what do you exactly want (enable when `T` is `const` or isn't `const`; if you have a function that print value of some types it's necessary wrap it in a template class? Can't you apply SFINAE directly over the function?) anyway... some useful elements...

(1) starting from C++11 there is `std::is_const` that you can use to check if a type is constant or not

(2) to make an example, a possible way to enable a specialization only for constant types is the following

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct print;

template <typename T>
struct print<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_const<T>::value>::type>
 {
   print (T line)
    { std::cout << line << std::endl; }
 };
```

The specialization can be simplified, starting from C++14, using `std::enable_if_t`

```
struct print<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_const<T>::value>>
```

and, starting from C++17, also using `std::is_const_v`

```
struct print<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_const_v<T>>>
```

(3) you can enable/disable directly the constructor, but only making is a template one (or SFINAE can't work)

```
template <typename T>
struct print
 {
   template <typename U = T,
             typename std::enable_if<std::is_const<U>::value, int>::type = 0>
   print (U line)
    { std::cout << line << std::endl; }

   // possible alternative do-nothing constructor for not const values
   template <typename U = T,
             typename std::enable_if<! std::is_const<U>::value, int>::type = 0>
   print (U)
    { }
 };
```

Observe that, in this case, the SFINAE tests (`std::is_same` and `std::is_const<U>`) are (also) over the template parameter of the constructor, `U`, not over the template parameter of the class, `T`. Otherwise SFINAE doesn't works.

The first `std::enable_if` impose that `T` and `U` are the same.